# A bad/mild dose of flu (meaning)

Tags: meaning, expressions

I came across these two expressions "a bad dose of" and "a mild dose of", in the context of an illness. I wonder if the following meanings are correct.

> - a bad dose of flu = very ill with flu
> - a mild dose of flu = slightly ill with flu

Is there an expression to express something like a midpoint?
I wonder if those expressions are American English. If not, what is the equivalent of them in American English?

Examples:

> 1. *John had a bad dose of flu*.
> 2. *Veronica has a mild dose of flu*.

Comment: I have never heard "dose of flu" in AmE. We would say "a bad/mild **case** of the flu" or just "a bad/mild flu"

Comment: A midpoint might be a "moderate" (or "moderately bad") dose/case of flu.

Comment: "A dose of flu" is BrE. Your meanings are perfectly correct. A midpoint would be **flu**!